# Get all columns with matching headers and plot in R

Tags: r

I have 3 files where each column belongs to a sample.  I ultimately need to plot x vs. y. However, my x values are in one file and the corresponding y values are in another file. There are over 200 files so I don't want to pick col1 from all files manually.

I would like to grab all three based on the headers and send to a new file. If its easier, I can also just plot directly by setting file 1 as x value and set the corresponding matches from file 2 as the y value.  Not sure which is easier, I've tried looping and merging, but I can't get it to work right. I'm using R but am open to anything that would help.

Tried this so far in R:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(m)) {
  a <- data.frame(m[, i])
  myfile <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0(i, ".txt"))
  write.table(a, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
          quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
}
```

File 1 looks like this (x value):

```
ATP6V1H SLC24A1 STK17B
0.05934657  0.9567147   0.05235321
0.07479263  0.9372463   0.05292247
0.09478673  0.9470376   0.04198125
0.1288194   0.9519405   0.06007662
```

File 2 looks like this (y value):

```
ATP6V1H SLC24A1 STK17B
1.6378678   -0.07271993 1.09079677
-0.49133659 1.6378678   0.41088151
0.14582699  -0.10920048 0.80591848
-0.07271993 -1.02715427 -1.51238959
```

File 3 looks like this (factor to color code):

```
ATP6V1H SLC24A1 STK17B
4   4   4
4   4   4
4   4   4
0   0   0
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help

```
x <- read.table("x.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
y <- read.table("y.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
color <- read.table("color.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")

headername <- names(x)

for(i in 1:length(headername)) {

  combinedresult <- cbind(x[headername[i]],y[headername[i]],color[headername[i]])
  colnames(combinedresult) <- c("x","y","color")
  write.table(combinedresult,paste(headername[i],".txt",sep=""),quote=TRUE,row.names = FALSE)

}
```

this will give you three files with each column name and output of each file would be like

```
"x" "y" "color"
0.05934657 1.6378678 4
0.07479263 -0.49133659 4
0.09478673 0.14582699 4
0.1288194 -0.07271993 0
```

Comment: Hi Aafaque, I just tried your suggestion. It works perfectly!!!!!!!  Thanks you soon much!!!!! I was making it harder on myself!

Comment: Hi @Aafaque. I have a question. Is there a way to modify this to look for matching header names? As of now, it only gives me the matching columns based on its number, i.e [1] or [2], but it returns the wrong values.

Comment: I already mentioned based on matching header names
If you check 
"headername <- names(x)" 
Here I am storing header names in an array of strings
then based on header names headername[i] , matching the columns

hope this answers your question , otherwise let me know if i understood your question wrong